# removing files which are in one folder from another folder linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I have two directories.
`DirA` contains all the files which are in `DirB`.
I want to remove all the files which are in `DirB` from `DirA`.
How one could do it in linux command line?

I am using ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cd DirB
for i in *
do
    rm DirA/"$i"
done
```

**Edit:** Use double-quotes around `$i` to handle filenames containing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that i for loop:

```
for f i DirB/*; do
    fn="${f##*/}"
    [[ -f "$fn" ]] && rm -f "DirA/$fn"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example, with execution output, which would work also if filenames would contain spaces (an uncomfortable thing which I don't recommend, by the way):

```
root@folgore:/tmp/test# tree
.
├── DirA
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   ├── c
│   └── d
└── DirB
    ├── a
    ├── b
    ├── e
    ├── g
    ├── h
    └── r

2 directories, 10 files
root@folgore:/tmp/test# for f in `ls DirB/* | sed 's/ /_SPC_/g'`;do fa=`echo $f | sed 's/_SPC_/ /g;s/^DirB\//DirA\//'`;echo "removing $fa if exists";rm -f "$fa";done
removing DirA/a if exists
removing DirA/b if exists
removing DirA/e if exists
removing DirA/g if exists
removing DirA/h if exists
removing DirA/r if exists
root@folgore:/tmp/test# tree
.
├── DirA
│   ├── c
│   └── d
└── DirB
    ├── a
    ├── b
    ├── e
    ├── g
    ├── h
    └── r

2 directories, 8 files
```